# Alterar Elemento mouseover/mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando alterar o `src` de um elemento utilizando a propriedade `attr` no `mouseover` e depois no `mouseleave`.
A ideia é alterar um banner enquanto o mouse está sob um elemento e atualizar novamente, após sair.

Tentei de duas formas:

1º

```
    $('.quartaImagem').mouseover(function () {
        $(".banner").attr("src", "Content/img/fotosHome/treinamentos.jpg");
    });
    $('.quartaImagem').mouseleave(function () {
        bannerDefault;
    });
```

2º

```
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $('.quartaImagem').hover(function (e) {
            $(".banner").attr("src", "Content/img/fotosHome/treinamentos.jpg");
        }, function (e) {
            $(this).attr('src', bannerDefault);
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve fazer algo assim:

```
var bannerDefault; // declara a variável no escopo global
$('.quartaImagem').hover(function (e) {
    bannerDefault = $(".banner").attr("src"); // memoriza o src atual
    $(".banner").attr("src", "Content/img/fotosHome/treinamentos.jpg"); // define novo src
}, function (e) {
    $(".banner").attr('src', bannerDefault); // define o src que estava antes
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/cuc984n5/)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!